How to fade in elements to a specified opacity percentage?
CSS that applies the opacity for the element
#urlTextOne {
    opacity: 80%; 
}

I have JS that applies the 'fadeIn' class to the element after page load
.fadeIn {
    animation: fadeIn 5s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 80%;}
    
}

Here's the JS that removes the display none and then add's the class to fade in
urls[i].classList.remove('d-none'); 
urls[i].classList.add('fadeIn');

I tried using the CSS animation above but it fades from fully opacity into no opacity and then flashed to the 80% opacity. I'm confused why the animation goes to no opacity and then jumps to the 80%. Additionally, I never remove the class that applies the 80% opacity.

I would try setting the default opacity of the element to 0 not 80%

We don't have enough info to help. Please read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

use opacity: 0.8; instead of opacity: 80%;

It seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/9v7kxepj/4/

@Squirrl it does seem to work there, I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help though

I SOLVED IT, i forgot to remove my animate.css link, oops.
